# See django.db.backends logs in stdout on pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-south

I got a problem on `Pycharm`.

When I run my tests I can't display `django.db.backends` logs on `stdout/stderr`.

When I use `runserver` it works like a charm.

Do you have any simple solution to display all logs with `level=DEBUG` on stdout on **my tests?**

More info:

- my `DEBUG` is set to `True` in my settings
- I use `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False` and `SKIP_SOUTH_TESTS = True`

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think south is involved? Why do you mention it?

Comment: I don't know if South disable some logging, but I don't want to execute south migrations to speed up my tests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, django forces settings.DEBUG to False during UnitTest ([Writing and running tests in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/#other-test-conditions)).
So you should activate temporary this settings using *`override_settings`* decorator:

From django documentation:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.utils import override_settings

class LoginTestCase(TestCase):

    @override_settings(LOGIN_URL='/other/login/')
    def test_login(self):
        response = self.client.get('/sekrit/')
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/other/login/?next=/sekrit/')
```

But reading the django source code, you can also set the *`use_debug_cursor`* attribute of the *`connection`* object. If set to True, the `CursorDebugWrapper` will be used and queries logs will appear.

Extract from django source (`django/db/backends/__init__.py`):

```
class BaseDatabaseWrapper(object):
    # [...]
    def cursor(self):
        self.validate_thread_sharing()
        if (self.use_debug_cursor or
            (self.use_debug_cursor is None and settings.DEBUG)):
            cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
        else:
            cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
        return cursor

    def make_debug_cursor(self, cursor):
        return util.CursorDebugWrapper(cursor, self)
```

Answer (score 2):

I dare say it's got nothing to do with pycharm.  It's standard python you're battling with.
First glance it seems you're just asking how to configure the logging to be noisier.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Admittedly i'm not making any real effort here, but perhaps something like this in your settings file will give you ideas...

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'simple':   {'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'},
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console':     {'level': 'DEBUG', 'class': 'logging.StreamHandler', 'formatter': 'simple'},
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {'level': 'DEBUG', 'handlers': ['console'], 'propagate': False},
}
```

Comment: thank you John Mee, but I still don't see my django.db.backends requests in my tests : here a part of my settings.py http://pastebin.com/mjdiCycD

Comment: ah, oui. Bon chance Monsieur.